# XSLT 2.0, I want to add all values of variable into one variable and then display

Tags: xslt-2.0

My Input is something like this below.

```
<XSL:variable name = "TotalAmount" > 
       <text>10;20;20;30;55.....</text> 
</xsl:variable>
```

I am expecting an output like below

output: 135 (sum of all the values separated by ';')

Answer (score 0):

You can compute `sum(tokenize($totalAmount/text, ';'))`.